# Getting INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY on SaveChanges()

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, entity-framework, exception, foreign-keys

I am new to working with the Entity Framework with SQL Server and I am having trouble inserting a record into my database. The problem is with 3 tables that are linked with primary keys and a foreign key and in the past I have not used databases with foreign keys.

I am just trying to get some test data into the database for now but I keep getting the error:

> *INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY*

Can anyone help me get started with inserting into my database please? Here is the code I am using:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TaxiDBEntities db = new TaxiDBEntities(); //connection to database
    DriverStatus newDriverStatus = new DriverStatus(); // driver status object

    /*populate the new driver object*/
    //newDriverStatus.DriverID = Convert.ToInt32(driverComboBox.Text);
    //newDriverStatus.Status = statusTextBox.Text;
    //newDriverStatus.Area = areaTextBox.Text;

    Driver driver = new Driver();

    int driverIDInt = Convert.ToInt32(driverComboBox.Text);

    //driver = db.Drivers.SingleOrDefault(p => p.DriverId == driverIDInt);
    //if (driver == null)
    //{
        driver.DriverId = driverIDInt;
        driver.Fname = "test";
        driver.Lname = "test";
    //}

    db.DriverStatus.AddObject(newDriverStatus); // add driver object to entity model

    DriverLog driverLog = new DriverLog();

    driverLog.driverLogID = driverIDInt;
    driverLog.DriverID = driverIDInt;
    driverLog.date = DateTime.Now;

    db.DriverLog.AddObject(driverLog);

    DriverStatus driverStatus = new DriverStatus();

    driverStatus.DriverID = driverIDInt;
    driverStatus.Status = "1";
    driverStatus.Area = "1";

    db.DriverStatus.AddObject(driverStatus);

    try
    {
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actual insert of the `driver` object into the database seems to be missing. After the line

```
driver.notes = "test";
```

you should have something like

```
db.Driver.AddObject(driver);
```

And then go on with creation of `driverLog` and `driverStatus` objects.

Answer (score 1):

You need to insert the driver into the database before you can add a status or a log.  The first thing you are doing after populating you driver object is adding a status

Answer (score 1):

1) You're getting your ID from a textbox, `int driverIDInt = Convert.ToInt32(driverComboBox.Text)`. That is not the best solution, consider making it an IDENTITY column.

2) Your model indoicates that Drive-DriverLog is 1-n but your code won't allow more than 1 Log:

```
driverLog.driverLogID = driverIDInt;
driverLog.DriverID = driverIDInt;
```

3) You are adding `newDriverStatus` to the Db but there are no keys set.

4) If you intended to link `newDriverStatus` to `driver` then adding `driverStatus` as well presents a conflict.

And, like others already noted, you forget to add `driver` to the db.

In summary, it is much easier to define your columns as INDENTITY and let the fx handle the foreign keys. Just use `newDriverStatus.Driver = driver;` and `driverLog.Driver = driver;`